# Get the indices of word sequences in texts represented as list of words

Tags: python, string, list, find

Given a paragraph represented as a list of words:

```
context = ['Katie', 'Joplin', 'is', 'an', 'American', 'sitcom', 'created', 'by', 'Tom', 'Seeley', 'and', 'Norm', 'Gunzenhauser', '.', 'The', 'sitcom', 'received', 'positive', 'reviews', 'thanks', 'to', 'the', 'brilliance', 'of', 'Tom', 'Seeley', '.']
```

And a list of multi-word target strings:

```
target = ['sitcom created', 'Tom Seeley']
```

How to get the indices of the multi word targets?

In this case answer should be:

```
[[5, 6], [8, 9], [24, 25]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `context` contains only single words (without spaces), you can join the context to single string and then use `str.index`:

```py
target = ["sitcom created", "Tom Seeley"]

out, joined = [], " ".join(context)
for t in target:
    try:
        idx = joined.index(t)
        cnt = joined[:idx].count(" ")
        out.append([cnt, cnt + t.count(" ")])
    except:
        continue

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[5, 6], [8, 9]]
```

---

EDIT: For multiple occurrences:

```py
target = ["sitcom created", "Tom Seeley"]

out, joined = [], " ".join(context)
for t in target:
    idx = 0
    while True:
        try:
            idx_new = joined[idx:].index(t)
            cnt = joined[: idx + idx_new].count(" ")
            out.append([cnt, cnt + t.count(" ")])
            idx += idx_new + len(t)
        except:
            break

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[5, 6], [8, 9], [24, 25]]
```

Comment: It works well for this context, but it only gives the first occurrence. If context had Tom Seeley repeated the code shall get all occurrences. I have amended context to contain this.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy does operations in C, so this should be one of most weird ways to solve it....lol....as we generally use it for numerical computation
Convert the arrays to numpy and then compare them using broadcast.
It assumes the multi-word targets are present in the array

```py
A = np.array(context)
B = np.array(['sitcom created'.split(), 'Tom Seeley'.split()])
np.argmax(A == B[..., None], axis=2)
# [[5, 6], [8, 9]]
```

```py
y = np.where(A == B[..., None])
pre_x, pre_y=(None, None)
l = []
for x, y, z in np.vstack(y).T:
    if x == pre_x and y == pre_y:
        l[-1][-1].append(z)
    elif x == pre_x and y != pre_y:
        l[-1].append([z])
    else:
        l.append([[z]])
    pre_x, pre_y = x, y
# [[[5, 15], [6]], [[8, 24], [9, 25]]]

from itertools import product
sum(map(list, map(lambda x: product(*x), l)), [])
# [(5, 6), (15, 6), (8, 9), (8, 25), (24, 9), (24, 25)]
```